# sqlite insert vs update vs replace

Tags: android, facebook, sqlite

I am a working on a project in which I retrieve data from facebook about friends of the user. Friends details vary some times while at the other times they are the same as the one stored in the db.

I can use the replace command to make sure that the db is consistent with whatever information I retrieve from the facebook.

My question is how efficient this technique will be? In other words, I can use two techniques:

- One is to use the replace command and replace the complete record blindly
- Second is to first check whether there is any difference from the record saved in the db and update only the fields that have changed

Which of these approaches is going to be more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that queuing up a number of sqlite commands in a row is much more efficient than is doing anything else in between, even just comparing a few values.

I'd strongly recommend that you just do an update command.  SQLite is fast.

My observation is that SQLite is always way faster than I am.  So let it do the heavy lifting and just dump the data at it, and let it sort out your updates.

For example, I was searching through about 7,000 records.  I pulled the records out into an array, did a quick check for one field, and separated it into two arrays.  This was taking me about 5 seconds.  I replaced it with two separate SQLite queries that each had to go through the entire data base.  The revised dual query takes about a quarter second, near as I can tell, because its so crazy fast.

I've had similar speed luck with Updates in my big database.

Comment: What do you mean by "queuing up a number of sqlite commands in a row" ?